# Python return True IF any 3 of 5 rows meet certain criteria Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in Python, I want to check if the `any` 3 out of the 5 numbers in `df.loc[1:5, 'code']` are less than 10, then return True

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'code' : [1,2,33,4,5,66,77,88,99,99]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.loc[1:5, 'code'] < 10
```

I'm not sure any() or np.where might work, please advise.

Comment: any() and np.any() works

Comment: @MkWTF can you kindly provide your solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question correctly. Scott Boston's sum solution is the way to go indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `sum`:

```
(df.loc[1:5, 'code'] < 10).sum() >= 3
```

Output:

```
True
```